# WNetAddConnection2 works with wrong credentials

Tags: windows, winapi, webdav

i've got a strange problem with using WNetAddConnection2.
First of all i connect to a WebDAV folder with correct server name, user name and password.
Connection get established as expected and i can see the mounted drive with the windows explorer.

After that i call WNetCancelConnection2 to remove the mounted drive. Works fine and it disappears from the explorer.

Now there comes the strange behaviour. If i try to connect again to the server it does not matter what password i use, i can take a totally wrong one and the drive get mounted again without any problems. Seems that Windows caches the connection.

I found out that it takes exactly one minute and after that time trying to connect will bring up the expected error message.

My question is if this 60 seconds timeframe is adjustable or what other thing i can do to avoid this behaviour.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just so you know. You're not crazy. I'm seeing this too. Down to the "wait 60 seconds" for the proper error message behavior. I tried turning off SMB2 but that didn't help me.